# Angular sends null Authorization Header

Tags: java, angular, spring, typescript

I am trying to send a request with an authorization header with Angular to a Spring backend.

```
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor{

    constructor(public sharedService : SharedService){}

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const jwtToken = this.sharedService.getJwtToken();

        if(jwtToken){
            req = this.addToken(req, jwtToken)
        }

        return next.handle(req)
   }

   addToken(req: HttpRequest<any>, jwtToken: any){
        return req.clone({
            headers: req.headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + jwtToken)
        });
   }
}
```

This is what my interceptor looks like. If I try to console.log() the authorization header before returning the next().handle , I can see the correct token inside the request. The problem is that the backend instead recieves a null Authorization header.

Inside by backend I have a doFilterInternal() method that filters any request and gets the Authentication header.
I don't think the problem is inside this filter because the request sent with Postman are handled correctly.
I have already enabled CORS on my backend

```
@Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry corsRegistry){
        corsRegistry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOriginPatterns("*")
                .allowedMethods("*")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .exposedHeaders("Authorization")
                .allowCredentials(true)
                .maxAge(3600L);
}
```

Comment: can you attach the console log of your returned token?

Comment: @s.katyan Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJxdWVsb0BnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJpYXQiOjE2NjkyOTQ1MDksImV4cCI6MTY2OTI5NTQwOX0.yl5o0iZwHI7BnB207lT...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After banging my head against the wall for several hours I found the solution.
When creating a class and implementing the WebMvcConfigurer (to enable CORS) this is right and it SHOULD work.

```
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry corsRegistry){
        corsRegistry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOriginPatterns("*")
                .allowedMethods("*")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .exposedHeaders("Authorization")
                .allowCredentials(true)
                .maxAge(3600L);
    }
}
```

BUT this isn't enough, since I had to enable CORS also into the security config chain

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable();

    return http.build();
}
```

by tiping `http.cors()`

Answer (score 0):

I believe token is not set, because `headers` property [is read-only](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest#headers).

Try to use `setHeaders` property of `clone` method argument:

```
addToken(req: HttpRequest<any>, jwtToken: any){
   return req.clone({
      setHeaders: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + jwtToken }
   });
}
```

Comment: Still nothing. At his point i think the problem is most likely in the backend

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue by making changes to the base URL in such a way that HttpClient sends requests over HTTPS instead of HTTP.